# Playwright locator(selector).click() not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, screen-scraping, playwright

I'm trying to scrape some data using playwright.
I click a button that opens a popup and after getting the data from popup, I need to click a 'Submit' button. I have tried using two ways:

```
let buttonSelector = await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Submit' });
await elm.click();

let elm = await popup.locator(buttonSelector);
 if(await elm.count() > 0){
   await elm.click();
 }
```

But getting an issue intermittently. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes gives below error.

```
Error: locator.click: Target closed.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator('input[type="button"][value="Submit"][class="someclass"]')
  locator resolved to <input type="button" name="search" value="Submit" class…/>
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  performing click action
```

Any idea how could this be handled?

PS. I have tried using $eval to perform programmatic click and it works perfectly with it. But $eval seems to be deprecated so can't use it.

Comment: Is the button actually visible and not overlapping with some other object?

Comment: Please check the screenshot and let us know.

Comment: I checked the visibility using .isVisible() and it gives true.

Comment: If possible try to provide the HTML and full source code. E.g. your example doesn't include `buttonSelector` so it's very hard to help. :)

Comment: @stefanjudis this is this selector
let elm = await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Submit' });

Comment: I don't follow.  `buttonSelector` still isn't defined in your example code. Please update the original question and provide as much information as possible so people can help. :)